# Save values from dynamic form in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a beginner in Reactjs and I am not finding the best way to save data from a dynamic form in ReactJS.
This form can only display 10 questions per page and when I move forward I have to save the answers on the current page.
Can anybody help me?
I was thinking of putting an ID on the form and then getting the component data....I have one form per component (inputs).

This is how I try to code my function that will save the answers and how I render the dynamic inputs

```
     save = (currentIndex, pageNumber) => {

            let {text="", id=""} = this.form.model;
            let answerText = text;
            if(Array.isArray(answerText)){
                text = JSON.stringify(text);
                answerText = answerText.filter(item=>!!item)
                if(!answerText.length) answerText = "";
                else answerText = text;
            }
            saveAnswerAction({
                answerId : id,
                text: answerText,
            }).then(()=>{

                return refresh();
            }).catch(e=>{
                console.log(e);
            });

        }

        render() {

            if (this.state.answers) {
                    var questions = this.state.answers.toJSON();
                    var questionsToRender = [];

                    var qInit = (this.state.currentPage * this.state.quantityQuestionsPerPage) - this.state.quantityQuestionsPerPage;
                    var qEnd = this.state.currentPage * this.state.quantityQuestionsPerPage;

                    if (qEnd > questions.length) {
                            qEnd = qInit + 1;
                    }

                    for (var i = qInit; i < qEnd; i++) {
                            var readOnly = false;
                            let QuestionRender = QuestionRenderFactory(questions[i], i, readOnly);
                            questionsToRender.push(<QuestionRender ref={form=>this.form=form} />)
                    }


                    return (
                            <div>
                                    {questionsToRender}
                            </div>
                    )
            }
            else {
                    return (
                            <div>
                                    NO QUESTIONS
                            </div>
                    )
            }

        }
```

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"formId_" + formId}>
                <p className="question">{questionAnswer.question.text} {questionAnswer.question.required ? <span className="question-required">* </span>: null }</p>        
                { questionAnswer.question.help && <div className="help">{questionAnswer.question.help}</div> }
                            
                <Form
                    ref={form => this.form = form}
                    value={this.state.model}
                    onChange={model => this.setState({ model })}>
                    {fields}
                </Form>
                <br />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I will have the HTML rendered:

```
<div class="content">
   <h3 class="title">Form</h3>

   <h3 class="subtitle">Fields * are required</h3>
   <br>
   <div>
      <div class="formId_0">
         <p class="question">
           Question 1<span class="question-required">* </span>
         </p>
         <div class="help">help</div>
         <form novalidate="">
            <div class="input-container undefined undefined">
               <div class="input-wrapper"><input name="text" class="  invalid-field" placeholder="" id="id_1" value="800b7e6e-ce0c-44bb-a4d8-60cffaacb509"><span class="inputError"><span class="validation-error">invalid field</span></span></div>
            </div>
         </form>
         <br>
      </div>
      <div class="formId_1">
         <p class="question">
            question 2<span class="question-required">* </span>
         </p>
         <div class="help">help 2</div>
         <form novalidate="">
            <div class="input-container undefined undefined">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <input type="text" name="text" class=" " placeholder="" id="id_2" value="www.test.com">
                  <span class="inputError">
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
         <br>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="buttons"><a class="btn skyBlue" href="/">Home</a><button class="btn-previous">Previous</button><button class="btn-next">Next</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage but I don't know if its efficient, secure, or the best route to go